# append h3 after fadeIn and fadout effect on h2

Tags: jquery

I want to append h3 after fadein and fadeout effect on h2. I tried but I did not getting. [fidde](http://jsfiddle.net/85kk6/)

```
$(function(){
    var jj= ['<h1>text1</h1>','<h2>text2</h2>','<h3>text3</h3>'];
    $.each(jj, function(i){
        $('body').append(jj[i])
        $('h2').fadeOut('slow').fadeIn('fast')
    })
})
```

Comment: do you want to show these elements in sequence... ie h1 first then h2 at last h3

Comment: like in http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xUSp8/1/

Comment: Your last statement is for `fadein` and `fadeout`, so technically fadein will occur after `h3` is appended. So you need to change the sequence of that.

Answer (score 1):

[Like this??](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/85kk6/1/)

```
var jj= ['<h1>text1</h1>','<h2>text2</h2>','<h3>text3</h3>'];

$('body').append(jj[0]);
$('body').append(jj[1]);

$('h2').fadeOut('slow').fadeIn('fast', function(){
    $('body').append(jj[2]);
});
```